# program catch the Arithmetic Exception and will demonstrate the finally block

Tags: java

I have problem. The coding is shown as below. When I run the program and enter "aaa", it shows error because it only catch arithmetic exception. How to add an appropriate codes to overcome the exception based on the problem occur?

```
import java.io.* ;
public class FinallyPractice1 
{
    public static void main(String [])
    {
        BufferedReader stdin=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String inData; int num=0, div=0;
        try
        {   System.out.println("Enter the numerator:");
            inData=stdin.readLine();
            num=Integer.parseInt(inData);

            System.out.println("Enter the divisor:");
            inData=stdin.readLine();
            div=Integer.parseInt(inData);

            System.out.println(num+"/"+div+"  is  "+(num/div));
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ae)
        {
        System.out.println("You can't divide "+ num + " by " + div);
        }
         catch(ArithmeticException aex)
         {
          System.out.println("You entered not a number: " + inData);
        }
        finally
        {
        System.out.println("If the division didn't work, you entered bad data.");
        }
            System.out.println("Good-by");
    }
}
```

[image]

I already find the answers! The coding  is like below:

```
 import java.io.* ;
    public class FinallyPractice1 
    {
        public static void main(String [] a) throws IOException
        {
            BufferedReader stdin=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String inData; int num=0, div=0;
            try
            {   System.out.println("Enter the numerator:");
                inData=stdin.readLine();
                div=Integer.parseInt(inData);

                System.out.println("Enter the divisor:");
                inData=stdin.readLine();
                div=Integer.parseInt(inData);

                System.out.println(num+"/"+div+"  is  "+(num/div));
            }
            catch(ArithmeticException ae)
                  {
                      System.out.println("ArithmeticException by " + div);
                  }
                    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ae)
                    {
                    System.out.println("You can't divide "+ num + " by " + div);
                 }
                    catch(NumberFormatException ae)
                    {
                  System.out.println("NumberException");
                 }
                    finally
                  {
                    System.out.println("If the division didn't work, you entered bad data.");
                 }
                      System.out.println("Good-by");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have forgotten to paste the code. Click [edit] and add it in.

Comment: would you mind to add your source code? Thanks.

Comment: `The coding is shows as below` where? This question is similar to your last but you haven't followed up on comments from that question encouraging you to be clearer as to what you want or are doing.

Comment: Maybe he's coding in whitespaces... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are deliberately inputting bad data "aaa", your statement:

```
div=Integer.parseInt(inData);
```

will throw a `NumberFormatException`. You could add a catch block for this:

```
...
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
   System.err.println(nfe);
  // more error handling
} catch ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Add one more `catch` block, like this:

```
    } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ae) {
        System.out.println("You can't divide "+ num + " by " + div);
    } catch(ArithmeticException aex) {
        System.out.println("You entered not a number: " + inData);
    } finally {
        //....
    }
```

Generaly, you can add as many `catch` blocks to a single `try` block as you want. But remember to give them correct order - place more specific exceptions first, and more generic - last.

If you want to catch any possible exception, you can use `Throwable` class:

```
try {
    // some potentially dangerous code
} catch (Throwable th) {
    // process error somehow
}
```

Comment: i already try to compile and run, but it shows identifier expected error.

Comment: have you imported ArithmeticException class?

Comment: what is your problem now? you still have " identifier expected error" ? if yes, you need to post more details

Comment: I already post the new coding that already imported ArithmeticException class. The error was shown in the image.

Answer (score 0):

add few more `catch blocks` to handle exceptions.

```
  catch(ArithmeticException ae)
        {
            System.out.println("ArithmeticException by " + div);
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ae)
        {
        System.out.println("You can't divide "+ num + " by " + div);
        }
        catch(IOException ae)
        {
        System.out.println("IOException");
        }
        finally
        {
        System.out.println("If the division didn't work, you entered bad data.");
        }
            System.out.println("Good-by");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new [multi-catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html). It has the from

```
catch (ArithmeticException |ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ae)
```

I would recommend you catch the exceptions you are expecting rather than just a blanket Throwable or Exception